# How to manually set colors in a bar chart

Tags: r

Currently the default colors for the below bar chart are Apct = Red , BPct = Green, CPct = Blue.

How do I change the color so that Apct = Purple, BPct = Black, CPct = Red?

Here is the working code:

```
library(reshape)
Time<-data.frame(Time = c(as.POSIXct("2015-02-05 14:35:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-02-05 14:40:00")))
APct<-c(.1,.2,.7)
BPct<-c(.2,.4,.4)
Time
data<-cbind(Time, rbind(APct, BPct))
data
colnames(data)<-c("Time", "APct","BPct","CPct")
rownames(data)<- NULL
data
data<-melt(data, measure.vars =c("APct","BPct","CPct") )
  ggplot(data=data, aes( x = Time,  y=value, fill=variable))   +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("% ") +  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Percentage") +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Also -

How do I know that purple will go with Apct? Is it alphabetically ordered or can I manaually set something liek Apct = Purple?

Also is there a way to make it so the Cpct is always the bottom bar, BPCt the middle bar and APct the top bar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `scale_fill_manual` to control the colours.

So your call to ggplot becomes

```
ggplot(data=data, aes( x = Time,  y=value, fill=variable))   +  
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
ggtitle("% ") +  xlab("Time") +
ylab("Percentage") +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("purple","black","red"))
```

Comment: Thanks xraynaud but how do I know that purple will go with Apct? Is it alphabetically ordered or can I manaually set something liek Apct = Purple?

Comment: is ther also a way to make it so the Cpct is always the bottom bar, BPCt the middle bar and APct the top bar?

Comment: your variables follow the order you specify in `measure.vars =c("APct","BPct","CPct")`(at least on my computer; I am not very familiar with `melt`. So you give the colours you want in the same order than your measure.vars argument and specify `measure.vars =c("CPct","BPct","APct") `to obtain the order you want.

Comment: Thank you  xraynaud. One more question do you know how to change the  legend order so that CPct is on the botto, BPct is in the middle and APCt on top in the legend. Just trying to match the legend with the bars. Than you.